# WPF ItemsControl and Togglebuttons weird behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol, togglebutton

I've been working on a WPF application but encountered some weird behaviour when using ItemsControl to display a list of togglebuttons with binding. It works just fine when it is displaying a collection of 1 element, but when I have two elements it behaves very strange. It will not show the image of both togglebuttons at once if they are in the same state (i.e. toggled on).

The relevant XAML. I have checked that the property behind is updated correctly, but let me know if there is any code that is needed.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ServiceItemsControl" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding DraftMessage.Services}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=Selected}">
                <ToggleButton.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                        <!--Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/-->
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Content">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Path=Service.OtherLogo}" Width="25" Height="25"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Content">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Service.Logo}" Width="25" Height="25"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ToggleButton.Style>
            </ToggleButton>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>       
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: have u tried providing a default image in trigger?

Comment: Not sure what that would solve, maybe I was a bit unclear. The images load properly and show up just fine one of the buttons is just collapsed (I guess?) when both of them have the same state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `DataTrigger` on the `Image` to change its `Source` property when the `ToggleButton.IsChecked` value is changed instead. Try this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}">
        <Image Width="25" Height="25">
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Service.OtherLogo}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, 
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type 
                            ToggleButton}}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{Binding Service.Logo}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
                <!--Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/-->
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>
</DataTemplate>
```